# Jenkins does not support 24 Clock on selenium running on Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, jenkins, timezone

I am using jenkins in order to run my tests in one of my tests (my test support 24 hour clock) I have to set time when I setting 10:00 it automatically saves it to 22:00 (I have no ability to define if it is AM or PM in the application itself). 
When I run my test locally (without using jenkins) it sets the time as I expect (10:00 am) what I need to add to my webdriver profile in order to solve this issue? anybody had similar problem?

Comment: MCVE, please?..

Comment: I am inserting 10:50 hour and when I ran it via Jenkins I get 10:50 PM and I don't have the option to select AM or PM .

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks.